# Folder hierarchy java web

Tags: java, html, jsp, web

[image]

I think that my folder hierarchy is wrong.

Should the `.html` and `.jsp` file is in `WEB-INF`?

I tried to move them there, but I received an `error 404`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/packaging003.htm#BCGHAHGD

Comment: so, my hierarchy is correct
is it right?

Answer (score 0):

No, everything you put in the WEB-INF folder will NOT be available to the users of your web application. Your hierarchy looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

WEB-INF resources not directly visible for the public. You can use webservlet annotation. For example;

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/adminlogin", "/register"})
```

or servlet mapping(old-fashioned),

web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>yourPackage.LoginController</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/adminlogin/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/logout/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/register/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/userlogin/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

LoginController

```
 //post get method 
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    String userPath = request.getServletPath();
    if (userPath.equals("/logout")) {
        //Your Model
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } ... 
 }
```